# APLpy coordinate change to pixel values

Tags: python, coordinates, aplpy

Does anyone know how to change the coordinate values to the pixel values of a fits file image in APLpy?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is just pass in the data-array instead of the fits file. If it has no WCS information it must operate in pixel-space.

```
from astropy.io import fits # or import pyfits
with fits.open(filename) as hdus:
    data = hdus[0].data
f1 = aplpy.FITSFigure(data)
# ... whatever you want to do thereafter.
```

I haven't used APLpy maybe there is a better way but I haven't found anything in the documentation.